# Set image to 100% height of the grid row that has its height based on its content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a layout with CSS grid, something like this |_|, but upside-down.

```css
.parent{
    width:500px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:grey;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-areas:
    "div1 div1"
    "div2 div3";
    grid-template-columns:auto 1fr;
    gap:10px;
}

.d1{
    grid-area:div1;
    background-color:pink;
}
.d2{
    grid-area:div2;
    background-color:beige;
}
.d2 p{
  margin:0;
}
.d3{
    grid-area:div3;
    background-color:aqua;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    
}
.d3 img{
    grid-area:div3;
    background-color:aqua;
    height:200px;
    aspect-ratio:1/1;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="d1">DIV 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="d2">
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d3"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/dog.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Right now, the image is set to a fixed height of 200px. Without it it would have its native size (way too big) What I'm trying to do is to set the image to be the same height as DIV2 (that has no fixed height). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
position: relative;
```

to .d3
and then to the .d3 image  add

```
position: absolute;  
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

you can then remove the height.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a more clean way? I'd rather the image have an influence on the other elements.

Comment: Don't know what you mean. It seems like you wanted the d3's content to decide the height of the image. If the image is supposed to influence other elements - set height to the image.

Comment: When I shrink the page the image doesn't have any effect on the other elements, like it would have when it was actually there. I can't set the height to a fixed value (like 200px), because it will stretch the second row's height. I think the easiest way to explain what I want is to set the second row to always match d2's height and then set d3's height (and the image) to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contain: size;` on the the `.d3` element so its content (the image) is not considered then you set `height:100%` to the image

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "div1 div1" "div2 div3";
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
}

.d1 {
  grid-area: div1;
  background-color: pink;
}

.d2 {
  grid-area: div2;
  background-color: beige;
}

.d2 p {
  margin: 0;
}

.d3 {
  grid-area: div3;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  contain: size;
}

.d3 img {
  grid-area: div3;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="d1">DIV 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="d2">
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d3"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/dog.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Similar solution to position absolute, but I'll take it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `height` of the parent element to `100vh` which is basically to take the full height of the viewport, and then set the `height` of the image to `inherit`.

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "div1 div1"
    "div2 div3";
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
}

.d1 {
  grid-area: div1;
  background-color: pink;
}

.d2 {
  grid-area: div2;
  background-color: beige;
}

.d2 p {
  margin: 0;
}

.d3 {
  grid-area: div3;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 50vh; /* added '100vh' so the parent always takes the viewport height */
}

.d3 img {
  grid-area: div3;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: inherit; /* changed the value to 'inherit' */
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="d1">DIV 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="d2">
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>DIV 2 Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d3"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/29841/dog.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the solution to my problem. I have 4 rows with "DIV 2 Lorem ipsum". They stretch d2 div, so it has a height "X". I want the image to have the same height "X", so EXACTLY the same as 4  "DIV 2 Lorem ipsum" rows.